# pod can't specify version well

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I follow smart [react-native-ios-charts](https://github.com/Jpadilla1/react-native-ios-charts) and update to new version by `pod install`

and I specify version below

```
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '2.3.1'
  pod 'Charts', '2.2.3'
end
```

but the version always incorrect like below output

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Charts (2.2.4)
Installing SwiftyJSON (2.3.2)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `MyApp.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.

Sending stats

Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 2 total pods installed.
```

how could I fix it?

thanks for your time.

Comment: What version of cocoapods are you running?

Comment: @max_ pod version `1.0.0`

Comment: Have you tried de-integrating cocoapods for this project and reinstalling? `gem install cocoapods-deintegrate; pod deintegrate; pod cache clean`

Comment: @max_  yes, I ever tried `pod deintegrate`, but I ensure that problem already exist before that :(

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. The Podfile is freezing the both the Charts and SwiftJSON pods correctly as the docs say [Specifying pod versions](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html#specifying-pod-versions).

I just tested this in the ChartsExplorer with this Podfile [react-native-ios-charts](https://github.com/Jpadilla1/react-native-ios-charts/blob/master/examples/ChartsExplorer/ios/Podfile) and had no problems.

This is the log output.

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Charts (2.2.3)
Installing SwiftyJSON (2.3.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 2 total pods installed.
```